# Multiple Comparisons Correction for Multiple ANOVA models - Include only terms of interest?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have a a biological dataset, in which I am fitting the following partial mixed ANOVA model (apologizes for the MATLAB syntax):

```
Baseline_Bio_Data,Post_Bio_Data ~ Treatment_Group*Response_Group + Age + 
                                  Sex + Baseline_Clinical_Scores
```

- `Baseline_Bio_Data` and `Post_Bio_Data` are my dependent variables, taken before and following a treatment.
- `Treatment_Group` is a 2 level categorical variable (participants underwent one of two treatments with no randomization)
- `Response_Group` is a 2 level categorial variable (those who responded to the treatment and those who did not)
- `Age`, `Sex`, and `Baseline_Clinical_Scores` are covariates I'd like to control for.

This leads to 6 between-level effects (treatment group, response group, baseline clinical scores, age, sex, and the interaction term) and 7 within-level effects (time and its interactions with the between-level variables). This leads to 13 estimates in total.

Now, I have to apply the same model to 100 different datasets in total (with each dataset representing a different part of the brain). In my field, the use of False Discovery Rate (FDR) for multiple comparison correction is common.

My question is: if I am only interested in the effects that contain time, treatment group, and response group (totalling to 7 estimates), and not interested in my covariates, can I only correct only for those estimates I am interested in?

I initially went ahead and corrected for all estimates (applying FDR to a 13 estimate x 100 brain region = 1300 matrix of p-values). Would it be wrong to exclude the estimates of no interest from this matrix?

Comment: If you were to residualize your outcome on the covariates, wouldn't the problem lead to disappear on its own?

Comment: You seem to be using baseline covariates as response variables and treatment outcome variables as independent variables.

Comment: Dear chl and Frank, thank you for the comments. chl - I never thought about that, but it would seem to do the trick. Since I have two independent variables of interest (treatment group and response group), would I run a regression independently for both with the covariates (age, sex, baseline clinical score), and then use the residuals from each model in my primary regression model of interest?